# Shop using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make it so users can buy items from a shop, I want to make it so they can buy however amount they'd like, buy four items, or buy six!

Now I'm having struggles finding how much the cart of the user is worth, I do have written the following code but I'm using a loop for it that won't find the cart's value since the code after just gets executed while the loop is running, I guess that's the problem (?). I guess I could use `async` loops but I'd rather not go that route, would there by any better strategy of finding the value of the cart? If so please explain!

This is the current code I have for trying to see if the user has enough money to buy the items,

```
    var shopList = m.list;

    var price = 0;
    for(x=0;x<shopList.length;x++){
        price=price + findValue(shopList[x].itemid);
    }

    if(price < getBalance(user)){
        //USER DOES HAVE ENOUGH BALANCE
    }else{
        //USER DOES NOT HAVE ENOUGH BALANCE
    }
```

Edit: I'd love to know if there is a better way of finding the value of the cart.

Comment: Why not make a `cartValue()` function and then go `if (cartValue() < getBalance(user))`. Inside that function: `shopList.forEach(function(item) { ... })`

Comment: @tadman I did indeed think of that, making a variable that would return a function written using the same code, but is it really the best way to use a `loop`?

Comment: The best way is `forEach` or if you're using something like [Lodash](http://lodash.com) then you have more options like `_.reduce`

Comment: "since the code after just gets executed while the loop is running", does that mean your `findValue()` function is asynchronous?

Comment: @tadman when I then return it after the foreach it returns 0..

Comment: @Kashif it's just a json lookup and return.

Comment: @Kashif yeah it's asynchronous, since it's launched after each other.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to include the new code that's not working.

Comment: I mean, it does the exact same now, just like the above code returns the price 0, however when I put it in a timeout after a second it does load properly, but I don't want to go that route..

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to add a property to your "m" object that represent the total cart value, and this property may be increased whenever an item is added to the list. This simplifies get the total amount around your application. One gold rule for developing is to "Make common case fast"

Comment: M returns whatever is sent by the socket, meaning that this is all editable for the user, he would be able to set its cart value to 0.01 and purchase a grand worth of goods.

Answer (score 0):

If `findValue()` is `async`, then you have little choice for not dealing with it through `async` constructs. You can refactor `findValue()` to return a Promise, then change the for loop to something like

```
var promises = shopList.map(function(item) {
  return findValue(item.itemid);
})

Promise.all(promises).then(function(values){
    var price = 0;
    for (x=0 ; x < values.length ; x++){
        price = price + values[x];
    }

    if (price < getBalance(user)){
        //USER DOES HAVE ENOUGH BALANCE
    } else {
        //USER DOES NOT HAVE ENOUGH BALANCE
    }
});
```